# finding out who open in an inbox , in outlook

Tags: outlook

we run our computers over a network and everyone has access to an email address used in part of the company, there is a slight issue, someone is opening up emails without dealing with the requests, so messages are changed to read and no one has dealt with the customer as the get overlooked, and of coarse everyone is denying opening the emails, this is obviously causing havoc with customer service.

so my question is.

is there anyway to see what computer/user or some sort of other id opened up the email?

it is Microsoft outlook.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: finding out who opened an email in the inbox, sorry dont know how i messed that title up!

Comment: Simply stepping down Inbox looking for an email you can answer will mark emails as read.  Once a team member has selected an email, they should move it to another folder.  That folder could be a joint folder named something like "Being answered" or you could have a folder per team member.  Once the email has been answered, it should be moved to folder "Answered".  The only emails in the Inbox should be those not selected by a team member.

Comment: Is everyone in the team supposed to be capable of answering any emails?  In which case, perhaps you need a rule that a team member should always select the oldest email.  Or perhaps you need a macro or a person who shares the emails out among the team.

Comment: BTW, you can edit the title and/or the question if you have made a mistake or want to add more information.  You can edit the title or question at any time.  You only have five minutes to edit a comment.

Comment: thanks Tony, this is more of a case of someone maliciously trying mess things up, perhaps just changing the password so only one person has access, this would have been my first thing to do but there will be times when that person is out doing business and someone is needed to answer the emails.  thank you for your reply and solutions though its greatly appreciated. and i tried looking for the edit button i couldn't at the time, I am kinda new here but again thanks for the info.

Comment: I am retired now but when I an employee, I had no access to passwords.  Our Technical Department controlled that sort of thing.  I had access to particular drives on the server and particular shared mail boxes because of who I was and the department to which I was assigned.  Perhaps your TD could provide a similar service for you.

Comment: A macro can detect and record a lot of the actions performed by a user.  Your Tech Dept could secretly install such a macro on each team member's computer.  You could install such a macro but not secretly although it could be hidden in something that was useful.  Reading an email (or simply stepping through it) sets the `UnRead` and `LastModificationTime` properties.  A macro running on an unused computer could check these properties (and others) every minute, say, and record when they change.  This might help identify the trouble maker.

Comment: Thank you very much!   i will have to look deeply into this idea.